# Visual Studio 2013 vb.net renaming variables not handling case sensitivity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 and VB.NET. When renaming variables using the IDE by right-clicking on the variable and selecting Rename it doesn't change references to the variable if it' just a casing change.  Example rename _TestDate to _testDate is not propagating the change throughout the file.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't this due to VB.NET not being case-sensitive? So all of those other references to the variable don't have to change.

Comment: Indeed, but the renaming should still work.

Answer (score 1):

As specified on [Refactoring and Rename Dialog Box (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckfya594.aspx) the location property holds `the namespace to search when you perform the rename operation.`. The field is disabled, thus you can't enter the namespace you want to look for the name in (which makes sense). In your case, it probably looks in `ClassA` and completes the renaming there, but it doesn't rename in `ClassB`. This just isn't possible with the Rename tool of Visual Basic.

There are third party plugins who can do this for you though:

- [CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/)
- [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

They both have 30 day trials for you to test out..

Comment: We have ReSharper.  It doesn't appear to work there either.  This is annoying.

Comment: Can you post an example code? It suspect its the code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do a double-rename, temporarily using an intermediate variable name:

Step 1) rename _TestDate to _XXTestDate

Step 2) rename _XXTestDate to _testDate